# Reading Google Cloud Run mounted secret

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-secret-manager

From my understanding, I should be able to mount a secret file to a Google Cloud Run service and be able to read the file later on. However, I keep getting an error: [Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read]. I've already tried changing the service account to have the Secret Manager Secret Accessor permission, but that didn't work either

Any pointers for how I could solve this?

Example of how I'm going about this:

<< in Google Cloud Run Service setup: set Secrets mount path to "/run/secrets/mySecret"

<< in config file that has path to secret

```
{
   mySecretPath: "/run/secrets/mySecret"
}
```

<< file reading function

```
import {readFile} from 'fs/promise'
async function readMySecret(path) {
  return await readFile(path, {
     encoding: "utf8"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you've set it up, the mount path is a directory. There are files within it for each version. Try reading `/run/secrets/mySecret/latest` intead.